# How can I check only file name not extension is exists

Tags: php

How can I check only file name not extension like `jpeg, jpg, doc, xls`. and then copy its complete name like `example.jpeg` or `example.doc`

and if possible can we store its upper two parent directory like

if example.jpeg stored in

```
main_dir/second_dir/example.jpeg
```

so I want to store this path in php variable.

I know I can use `glob()`

```
$result = glob ("./uploads/filename.*");
```

and check `$result` value.

But I want to store complete file name and possible its two parent directory path.

Below is my code

```
$filename = '/www/test1/'. $file . '*' ;
if (count(glob($filename)) > 0) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

**Edit**

Updated query as per luweiqi solution

```
foreach(glob("/uploads/".$productnumber."/". $productnumber."b.*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $file) {  
        echo "Filename: " . $file . "<br />";      
        $image2 = "/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$file;
    }
```

Last letter of image varies like a to f . so can you make some correction in it. 
I want to check image is exist on uploads/productnumber/productnumber (a/b/c/d/e/f).jpg or png or jpeg etc. and store that file name in php variable.

Comment: Well the real question is: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Hi Naruto, Just waiting for this question. please check update question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function.

```
$pngFile = '/path/to/foo.png';
$docFile = '/path/to/foo.doc';
// Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.
if (file_exists($filename) || file_exists($docFile)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

OR

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function

```
$files=[];
$result = glob ("/path/to/foo.*");  
foreach ($result as $file) { 
     echo "$file size " . filesize($file) . "\n";       
     $files[] = $file; 
} 
echo '<pre>'; print_r($files);
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, I have updated my question. can you please check once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<?php

    foreach(glob("../directory/*{a,b,c,e,f}.*", GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
        echo "Filename: " . $file . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

This code would get the file name and echo it, you can change it accordingly if you want to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Let me try this .. Can I use php variable in path using proper concatenation like. my directory structure based on product_no.

Comment: @John I don't understand your context, maybe elaborate in your question what you're trying to achieve, thanks

Comment: foreach(glob("/uploads/".$productnumber."/". $productnumber."b.*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $file) {  
        echo "Filename: " . $file . "<br />";      
        $image2 = "/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$file;
    }  
Last letter of image varies like a to f . so can you make some correction in it. I want to check image is exist on uploads/productnumber/productnumber(lastletter like a b c).jpg/png etc. and store that file name in php variable.